# Codeigniter CMS with tinymce

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I am using tinymce to try and create a cms module but its not working nothing is showing in the view except for the text Manage contacts. Any idea why ? my js folder is in the same directory where my application folder is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>CMS</title>
        <script src="<?php echo base_url() ?>js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea",
    plugins: [
        "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",
        "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
        "insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste"
    ],
    toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image"
});
</script>
    </head>
    <body>
            <div id="page-wrapper">   
                <br>
            <div class="col-xs-9 col-md-12">
            <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading"><center> Manage Contacts</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
             <form action="<?php echo base_url() . "administrator/update_contacts"; ?>" method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form">

             <?php foreach ($contacts as $cms): ?>
                        <div class="form-group">

                                <?php 
                                  $value = $cms->hto;
                                $data = array(
              'name'        => 'contacts',
              'id'          => 'contacts',
              'value'       => $value,

              'style'       => 'width:100%',
            );

                                 echo form_textarea($data);
                                ?>

                             <?php $start = strtotime('6-07-2015');
                              $end = strtotime(date('Y-m-d'));
                              $result = ($end - $start) / (60 * 60 * 24);
                              print $result; ?>

                            </div>
                 <center><button type="submit" class="btn btn-success navbar-btn">DONE
                          </button>

                                </div>

 </form>       
                    <?php endforeach; ?>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: start with one contact and get that working first. then do your foreach for multiple contacts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you do a view source and see if you can actually access the js folder? Most probably you can not.

You will need to allow the js to be accessed outside of the protection of Codeigniter using .htaccess.

Something like this would work:

```html
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|js|robots\.txt)
 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.+)/$
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]
 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

You can easily add other folders next to the js folder as well.

Comment: hi i tried using the code you gave but when i try to access the project the links turns to www.localhost.com making the project not accessible

Comment: For localhost use this:

`RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]`